# array that starts a new activity

Tags: android, android-activity

OK, I realize this is prolly pretty basic, but im so new to this its unreal.

What I have is an array. What I want is for when a user clicks an item in the array, it opens a new activity that is specific to that item. Its a list of festivals, and when you click on one of the festivals, and when you click on it, it opens an activity that provides information about that festival.

I have no idea what I'm doing here. Im pretty sure I need to use an OnClickListener, but thats it.

Activity

```
 package com.MADONK.LAFESTS;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Home extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, Festivals));

   ListView lv = getListView();
   lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
         int position, long id) {
       // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
       Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   });
 }

    static final String[] Festivals = new String[] {
    "Lake Arthur Regatta", "Contraband Days", "Iowa Rabbit Festival",
     };
}
```

Comment: Post some code some will hellp

Comment: when you say you have an array, you mean you have a ListView and you've hooked up an ArrayAdapter to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're extending `ListActivity`, you can override `onListItemClick()`. You could do something like this, which gets the appropriate `Festival` object, and passes a member of it into an `Intent`, the `Intent` is then used to start another `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Festival item = (Festival) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(),YourFestivalDetailActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("some_attribute", item.getSomeAttribute());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

And then in the `Activity` you start that is meant to show the Festival detail, which in the above example is called `YourFestivalDetailActivity`, you should extract the Festival information from the `Intent` used to start it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String someAttribute = getIntent().getStringExtra("some_attribute");
}
```

Note that in this example I only pass a single `String` via the `Intent`, but know that you can pass more than that via an `Intent`. [See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29).

Comment: so, to understand a little bit better, how does it know which activity to start? or is it just 1 activity and it calls the required information from something else to display? and if so, where is the info stored?

Comment: In the first code snippet, you'll see that I made up an Activity called YourFestivalDetailActivity. Since I'm passing that in to the Intent constructor, the startActivity line below that knows to start that Activity. You should create an Activity (don't forget to add it in your AndroidManifest.xml file), and that activity should implement the code from the 2nd code snippet above. The idea is that you pass your Festival information as extras within an Intent, and the Activity that is started with that Intent can then extract the Festival information and assign it to TextViews or whatever else.

Comment: so the information is saved in the manifest? or is it saved in a layout.xml and the second snippet tells it which xml to call based on the position of the item in the array?

Comment: Oh boy. Sorry, but no. I mentioned AndroidManifest.xml because every Activity that you create in your application must be declared there, otherwise your app will crash when you try to start the new Activity. You need to create a new Activity meant for displaying the Festival information. The Festival information will come from the list in your main ListActivity which you've called "Home". You will pass the info about a Festival and start the new Activity using an Intent (which is what my code above does).

Comment: The 2nd snippet of code should go in the Activity that is meant to show festival data, it will pull the data out of the Intent used to start it and use the data to populate different views such as TextViews or ImageViews.

Comment: so how do I tie the information to the array item? I am so sorry, I'm still trying to learn this stuff, I'm getting is slowly but surely.